# How to handle redirect by httpClient fluent?

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm writing acceptance tests with HttpClient fluent api and have some trouble.

```
@When("^I submit delivery address and delivery time$")
public void I_submit_delivery_address_and_delivery_time() throws Throwable {

    Response response = Request
            .Post("http://localhost:9999/food2go/booking/placeOrder")
            .bodyForm(
                    param("deliveryAddressStreet1",
                            deliveryAddress.getStreet1()),
                    param("deliveryAddressStreet2",
                            deliveryAddress.getStreet2()),
                    param("deliveryTime", deliveryTime)).execute();
    content = response.returnContent();
    log.debug(content.toString());
}
```

This code works well when I use post-forward strategy, but an exception is thrown when I use redirect instead.

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Found
```

What I want is getting the content of the redirected page. Any idea is appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [HTTP specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) requires entity enclosing methods such as POST and PUT be redirected after human intervention only. HttpClient honors this requirement by default. .

```
10.3 Redirection 3xx

   This class of status code indicates that further action needs to be
   taken by the user agent in order to fulfill the request.  The action
   required MAY be carried out by the user agent without interaction
   with the user if and only if the method used in the second request is
   GET or HEAD.
```

...

```
   If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other
   than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
   request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
   change the conditions under which the request was issued.
```

One can use a custom redirect strategy to relax restrictions on automatic redirection if necessary.

```
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy());
    Executor exec = Executor.newInstance(client);
    String s = exec.execute(Request
            .Post("http://localhost:9999/food2go/booking/placeOrder")
            .bodyForm(...)).returnContent().asString();
```

Comment: +1, your code works well. Thank you for the response, I'm curious about the human intervention you mentioned, when I submited the form on browser manually, the page was redirected automatically, it seemed that I didn't need to do anything. So what's the human intervention here?

Comment: @Hippoom: See updates. A human intervention would probably be in a form of a UI dialog with 'Confirm' / 'Cancel' choices

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused and novice I am. I tried with several browsers(chrome, firefox, ie), all of them redirect automatically. Do they cover the intervetion for users for convenience(I think it's quite annoying to click confirm or cancel for users)?

Comment: @Hippoom: dark and wrong ways of browsers are. In HTTP specification wisdom you must seek. [I am sorry. I just could not resist it]

Comment: :) Looks like a variation of some famous saying?

Comment: To prevent deprectaion warnings that I encountered with Version 4.3.1, use HttpClientBuilder instead af calling the DefaultHttpClient constructor: HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();

Comment: However, directly below that statement in spec, it also states: “Note: RFC 1945 and RFC 2068 specify that the client is not allowed to change the method on the redirected request. However, most existing user agent implementations treat 302 as if it were a 303 response, performing a GET on the Location field-value regardless of the original request method. The status codes 303 and 307 have been added for servers that wish to make unambiguously clear which kind of reaction is expected of the client.”

The Post-Redirect-Get pattern is ubiquitous on the web.

Answer (score 2):

This is for an updated version of apache:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = 
  HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
.build();
```